# stopwatch PowerShell input

Tags: powershell

I have simple issue, but it is very hard to me to solve it.

I want a stopwatch, when I put a time in seconds and next MessageBox appear. 
It works when I input a number (10, 50, 120), but doesn't work when I put `60+5` or `60*2`.

How I can convert `60*2` to `120` in PowerShell?

```
[int]$time = Read-host "Write a time"
Start-Sleep $time
[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Tea!")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Invoke-Expression` might be safe if it can be limited to only numeric calculations.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

$userentry = Read-Host -Prompt "Write a time"

if ($userentry -match '^[\d+\-\*/\(\) ]*$') {
    try {
        $time = Invoke-Expression -Command $userentry -ErrorAction Stop
        Start-Sleep $time
        [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show('Teal')
    } catch {
        Write-Host 'ERROR: Invalid numeric expression'
    }
} else {
    Write-Host 'ERROR: Not a valid numeric expression'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try `Invoke-Expression $time` to evaluate expressions like this. But be aware, that all types of PowerShell-Code can be send by this

Comment: To illustrate the security issues with this answer - you could type `Restart-Computer` into the `Read-host` prompt and it would restart your computer. That's a nice example `Remove-Item` could do more damage, you even could install any software you want with this method.